# images to the center of the div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

all the images should be center aligned irrespective to its size.
i have tried with below code, but it doesn't work for me.
any help would be appreciated

```css
.border-class{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  min-height:160px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-3"> 
   <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">   
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons-gesture-stroke/32/icon_27_one_finger_click-128.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">   
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"> 
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *i want all the images to be center aligned both vertically and horizontally* is a pretty vague description for what you *actually* want to achieve. What have you tried so far? Do you have an example what you want?

Answer (score 6):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Just add Flex properties to `.border-class`

```
.border-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

See the snippet below:

```css
.border-class{
  /* Add these 'flex' properties */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:5px;
  min-height:160px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-xs-3"> 
   <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">   
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons-gesture-stroke/32/icon_27_one_finger_click-128.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">   
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"> 
  <div class="border-class">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"/> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `cover` property of `background-size` :

```
background-image : ...
background-size : cover;
background-position : center;
```